# no req.body sent on POST requests

Tags: node.js, post, express, request

After reading many similar threads, I failed to see the reason of my problem...

Im trying to learn how to create a RESTful API with node and express 4, pretty basic and simple, but when i try to save my document with a POST req, no req.body is sent on the request and i have some problems.

Lets look a little piece of code:

```
module.exports = (router, Bear) ->
  router.route '/bears'
    .get (req, res) ->
      Bear.find (err, bears) -> if err then err else res.json bears

    .post (req, res) -> 
      newBear =
        _id: req.body.bearId
        nombre: req.body.nombre
      bear = new Bear(newBear)
      bear.save (err) ->
        if err then res.send err 
        # res.json msg: "#{bear.nombre}, creado"
        res.json msg: "created"
```

So far, this is my basic routes config (for now). The server is:

```
express = require 'express'
app = express()
morgan = require 'morgan'
bodyParser = require 'body-parser'
mongoose = require 'mongoose'

app.use bodyParser.urlencoded extended: true
app.use bodyParser.json()
app.use morgan 'dev'

require('./app/config/js/database')(mongoose)

router = express.Router()
Bear = require './app/models/js/bear'

router.get '/', (req, res) -> res.json msg: 'It works'

require('./app/routes/js/bears')(router, Bear)

app.use '/api', router

port = 8080

app.listen(port)
console.log("Corriendo en #{port}")
```

And the other pieces of code are not relevant here (i think), so, when i send a request using postman, or CURL, i get always a `{}` response and a crash message on my server:

```
home/nano/Dev/bears/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:413
        throw err;
              ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/nano/Dev/bears/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:662:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/nano/Dev/bears/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:146:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/nano/Dev/bears/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:235:15)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/nano/Dev/bears/app/routes/js/bears.js:22:20)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/nano/Dev/bears/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:172:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (/home/nano/Dev/bears/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.reject (/home/nano/Dev/bears/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:111:15)
    at Promise.error (/home/nano/Dev/bears/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:95:15)
```

Really i have no idea I really have no idea what to do, I have all afternoon and into the night in this.

Well, i make the changes in the code and now the traceback desapeared but the request still going empty.

```
module.exports = (router, Bear) ->
  router.route '/bears'
    .get (req, res) ->
      Bear.find (err, bears) -> 
        if err then return res.send err 
        res.json bears

    .post (req, res) -> 
      newBear =
        _id: req.body.bearId
        nombre: req.body.nombre
      bear = new Bear(newBear)
      bear.save (err) ->
        if err then return res.send err
        res.json msg: "created"
```

The JS code:

```
(function() {
  module.exports = function(router, Bear) {
    return router.route('/bears').get(function(req, res) {
      return Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }
        return res.json(bears);
      });
    }).post(function(req, res) {
      var bear, newBear;
      newBear = {
        _id: req.body.bearId,
        nombre: req.body.nombre
      };
      bear = new Bear(newBear);
      return bear.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }
        return res.json({
          msg: "created"
        });
      });
    });
  };

}).call(this);
```

I'm sending the request via RESTClient for Firefox, Curl, Postman ... the content type header is `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Can you point out where the relevant lines from the stack trace are?  For example, `bears/app/routes/js/bears.js:22`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with **CoffeeScript** so I can't post an example. But it seems the query has an error and `if err then res.send err` is being executed. Then `res.json msg: "created"` is executed as well. Do you need to use `return` in **CoffeeScript** in this situation? Also might want to see if there actually is an error first.

Comment: +1 for seeing line 22

Comment: How are you posting to the server? XHR? HTML form? If so, what does that look like (specifically, what Content-Type/enctype is the form/request)?

Comment: Done, added the js code for the route and the Content-Type details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you comment out:

```
Bear = require './app/models/js/bear'
```

and replace:

```
require('./app/routes/js/bears')(router, Bear)
```

with:

```
router.post "/bears", (req, res, next) ->
  console.log req.body
  res.json req.body
  return
```

you will see that the req.body is coming through.

As mentioned in the comments, there is a missing **return** statment in your **bears.coffee** route file. You need to change line 12 so that it reads:

```
if err then return res.send err
```

Make sure that you are sending your parameters in the body of the request. For curl you should use:

```
curl -X POST -d "bearId=1221&nombre=papa" http://localhost:8080/api/bears
```

For Postman, make sure you choose POST from the dropdown and that you click on x-www-form-urlencoded and put your parameters in the "Key" and "Value" fields respectively.

Comment: Replacing the code of requires and putting the bare post, the request still going empty:

`-{}
POST /api/bears?_id=4&nombre=pepel 200 67.580 ms - 2`

Comment: Well, after seeing your request, you are putting your request parameters in the URL instead of the body. Those would be accessed using req.param instead of req. body. For a POST request you should pass them in the body. If you are using Postman, you need to make sure to click x-www-form-urlencoded and add your parameters in the "Key" and "Value" fields. I will update my answer.

Comment: It works, the problem are in the x-www-form-urlencoded... thanks for all!