# Timeout On POST Req Using MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm learning to create a RESTful API using Node and Express 4.0 and am having trouble just getting the POST req to work properly when tested with Postman in Chrome. The request times out when the save method is called (I think--I'm new to this).

Here's my base code:

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');   
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@ds033484.mongolab.com:33484/testdatabase');

var Dog = require('./app/models/dog');

var router = express.Router(); 

router.route('/dogs')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var dog = new Dog();
        dog.name = req.body.name; 
        dog.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                return res.send (err);
            res.json({ message: 'Dog created!' });
        });

    });

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Code is testable on port ' + port);
```

app/models/dog.js:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var DogSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Dog', DogSchema);
```

I tested the code with Postman, selecting POST from the dropdown menu and selecting x-www-form-urlencoded from the Body tab. I filled in the key (name) and the value "Clifford."

The request timed out.

So I added a few console logs to server.js:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Router is in use.');
    next();
});

router.route('/dogs')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        console.log("Accessing Mongoose.");
        var dog = new Dog();
        console.log("New dog.");
        dog.name = req.body.name; 
        console.log("The dog is named: " + dog.name);
        dog.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                return res.send (err);
            res.json({ message: 'Dog created!' });
        });

    });
```

All of them show up, including "The dog is named: Clifford". As far as I can tell, that means it's a problem with the save method.

What should I be doing next? Any help would be much appreciated. I found a similar problem here: [no req.body sent on POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227843/no-req-body-sent-on-post-requests)

But OP here seems to just be using the wrong settings in his test and gets an error. The only error I get is the timeout.

Comment: what happens if you put a console.log inside the save function? is it being called properly?  that is, can you connect to mongo?

Comment: I just added the following log, and it doesn't show up in the console.

`dog.save(function(err) {
            
     console.log("I'm trying to save.");
            
          if (err)
                
               return res.send (err);
            
               res.json({ message: 'Dog created!' });
        
     });`

Comment: The timeout error says that it isn't connecting, but it seems to check the login without a problem (I checked that by typing in the wrong password in the MongoDB address and got the corresponding error).

Comment: what happens if you add some code to your server.js to create a dog and save it?  without someone connecting, just inline to test.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you ask me to save it inline. Could you give me an example?

Comment: just create a new dog object and save it, outside of the express boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you replace

```
router.route('/dogs').post(function(req, res) {});
```

by

```
app.post('/dogs', function(req, res) {});
```

By the way, if you're looking for a more efficient way to debug your node server than console.log(), I recommend [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector).

Comment: Replacing it as follows:

`app.post('/dogs', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Accessing Mongoose.");
        var dog = new Dog();
        console.log("New dog.");
        dog.name = req.body.name; 
        console.log("The dog is named: " + dog.name);
        dog.save(function(err) {
            console.log("I'm trying to save.");
            if (err)
                return res.send (err);
            res.json({ message: 'Dog created!' });
        });
});`

And I get "Cannot POST /api/dogs" in Postman.

Comment: I just cloned node-inspector and am looking forward to trying it out. This may be a good opportunity if this turns out to be a stranger issue to solve.

Comment: I believe we have the same exact code and it works for me. Sometimes silly errors happen, are you sure your node server and mongo server are up ? Whether it's now are later down the road, I am sure node-inspector will help you, it really is a nice tool.

Comment: I was re-thinking about your problem and figured that it could be helpful for you to see my own MEAN project's server.js. [Here](https://github.com/Nouzbe/sample-app/blob/master/server.js) it is. I hope it will help.